# Unable to resolve module './core/theming ' React-native cli

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to use AppBar

- "dependencies": { "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6", "react":
  "17.0.2", "react-native": "0.66.3", "react-native-paper": "^4.10.1",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0", "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E19h0.png

```
import React from 'react';
import { Appbar } from 'react-native-paper';

const Home = () =>{
    return (
    <Appbar.Header>
        <Appbar.Content title="title" />
    </Appbar.Header>
    )
    
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

I miss typed, it's not `<Appbar.Content title="title" />` instead `<Appbar.Content title={"title"} />`.

Comment: Hey, is this resolved ur error? Because both syntax is identical.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).